# Faithfullness of the Minkowski functional

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space. I need to show that the Minkowski functional $p_C$ for $C$ a convex open neighborhood of $0$ coming from the local base of convex sets, is faithful, that is, I must prove that for any $x \in X$, $x=0$ if an only if $p_C(x)=0$ for all $C$ as defined. The first way ($\Rightarrow$) is easy enough, but the other way ($\Leftarrow$) I am getting stuck. I have the feeling that the only way is through an indirect proof, but I can't figure out what the best strategy is.

Comment: Think about the Hahn-Banach theorem....

Comment: The seperation theorem or the extension theorem?

Comment: Think about it! Which one helps? That's the one you want to use, the one that works.

Comment: I can't see why any one of them should help since neither of them speaks about the Minkowski functional ? btw. I am not using Rudin's book so maybe that is why?

Comment: If $L$ is a bounded linear functional then the set of $x$ with $|Lx|\le1$ is convex... What would the Minkowski functional for that set be?

Comment: If $\mu_M$ denotes the Minkowski functional of $M=\lbrace x \in X \mid \vert Lx \vert \leq 1 \rbrace$, then $\mu_M(x) = \inf(\lbrace t>0 \mid t^{-1}x \in M \rbrace) = \inf(\lbrace t>0 \mid \vert L(x) \vert \leq t \rbrace)$, right?, Since we are taking infimum over positive numbers, this must be zero?

Comment: Right until the last sentence. What is the inf of $\{t>0:2\le t\}$?

Comment: Okay where does the 2 come from in your set?

Comment: That was just a random example, to illustrate the problem with your statement "Since we are taking infimum over positive numbers, this must be zero?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x=\mathbf{0}$. Let $C \in \gamma$ be arbitrary , where $\gamma$ is a local base of convex sets. Let $p_C$ be the Minkowski-functional associated with $C$. If $t=0$ it follows that:
\begin{equation}
p_C(\mathbf{0})=p_C(0\mathbf{0})=0p_C(\mathbf{0})=0
\end{equation}
Which was to be proved. Conversely, suppose $p_C(x)=0$ for all $C \in \gamma$ and assume for contradiction that $x \neq \mathbf{0}$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exists open neighborhoods $U_x$ and $U_\mathbf{0}$ of respectively $x$ and $\mathbf{0}$ in $X$ , such that $U_x \cap U_\mathbf{0} = \emptyset$. Since $X$ is locally convex the open neighborhood $U_\mathbf{0}$ contains an open, convex neighborhood $C' \in \gamma$. Since $C' \subseteq U_\mathbf{0}$ it follows that also $C' \cap U_x = \emptyset$. Hence $x \not\in C'$ and so the Minkowski functional $p_{C'}(x) \geq 1$. This contradicts that $p_C(x)=0$ for all $C \in \gamma$. Therefore, $x = \mathbf{0}$, as was to be proved.

This does not use the Hahn-Banach Theorem, I think.